# Suppose $G=\langle S \rangle$. Show $[G,G]$ is smallest normal subgroup containing $[S,S]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have a group G generated by a set S, i.e. $G=\langle S \rangle $. I am to show that the commutator subgroup of $G$ is the smallest normal subgroup containing $[S,S]$. Thus suppose $H$ is such a normal subgroup. I tried two approaches. First, it suffices to show that the generator of the commutator group are in H. So if $[g,g']\in G$ I tried to show $[g,g']\in H$, by trying to conjugate some $[s,s']$ by some element in $G$, but none of my attempts to do this worked. I showing this for $g=s_1s_2,g'=s_3,s_4$ and it did not work. I also tried an inductive argument on the length of the word $g$ by assuming $[g,s]\in H$ and trying to do something with $[gs',s]$. Second I tried to show that the quotient group $G/H$ is abelian, as then the kernel of $G\rightarrow G/H$ is $H$, and the commutator is inside the kernel of a homomorphism whose image is abelian. However here also I was unable to show $abH=baH$. Is there some other approach or am I messing up one of mine? Hope someone can help.

$\underline{\textbf{EDIT:}} \\$
I think I figured it out right after posting... So we need to show that $G/H$ is abelian. I.e. $abH=baH$. But notice that $a,b$ are words in $s_1,s_2,...$. Thus it suffices to show $s_1s_2H=s_2s_1H$. But notice that $[s_2,s_1] =s_2s_1s_2^{-1}s_1^{-1}=h\in H$ by assumption. Then we get $s_2s_1=hs_1s_2$, so that $h's_2s_1=(hh')s_1s_2$ so it is easy to see that $s_2s_1H=Hs_2s_1=Hs_1s_2=s_1s_2H$ as $H$ is normal in $G$.

Answer (score 1):

There is a theorem which states that a $f$ is a homomorphism such that $f(G)$ is abelian if and only if the commutator of $G$ is in $ker(f)$. Consider the map $G\rightarrow G/H$.  We need to show that $G/H$ is abelian, i.e. $abH=baH$, so that by the theorem the commutator of $G$ is contained in $H$. But notice that $a,b$ are words in $s_1,s_2,...$. Thus it suffices to show $s_1s_2H=s_2s_1H$. But notice that $[s_2,s_1] =s_2s_1s_2^{-1}s_1^{-1}=h\in H$ by assumption. Then we get $s_2s_1=hs_1s_2$, so that $h's_2s_1=(hh')s_1s_2$ so it is easy to see that (since h can be viewed as an automorphism) $s_2s_1H=Hs_2s_1=Hs_1s_2=s_1s_2H$ as $H$ is normal in $G$.